# C# поиск сертификата

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

Всем привет. Нужно найти на компьютере определенный сертификат. По какому атрибуту необходимо выполнять поиск? `serialNumber` я так понимаю не является уникальным.

Для поиска использую код:

```
X509Certificate2Collection certificates;                 
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);                    
certificates = store.Certificates.Find((X509FindType)filterType, filterValue, false);
store.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Поиск по отпечатку (Thumbprint):

```
var thumbprint = Regex.Replace("‎d2 46 8d 22 87 ab b7 00 35 e7 e1 cf d9 8f 6c 3d a7 cf c3 42", @"[^\da-zA-z]", string.Empty).ToUpper();

using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

    if (certificates.Count > 0)
    {
        var certificate = certificates[0];
        Console.WriteLine($"Субъект: {certificate.Subject}");
    };
}
```

Comment: А там using нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил using, почему то во всех примерах через try catch делают. Если объект store реализует IDisposable значит using норм?

Comment: Должно быть да.